# Android app seems to be duplicating when I swipe it away and start it again

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I am currently having a really weird issue, and I don't know what could be causing it. Every time I close the app by swiping it away, and then start it again, the app seems to be duplicating its output to logcat, or in other words, it appears to be running multiple times.

This doesn't happen when I am connected to Android Studio, but without a cable connection, it does it without fail.

In my main activity I start my service like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, BluetoothService.class);
startService(intent);
bindService(intent, bluetoothServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Stopping the service:

```
unbindService(bluetoothServiceConnection);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BluetoothService.class);
stopService(intent);
```

**EDIT** I have made some changes in the way I stop and start my service, which seems to have solved my problem on Android 5.1.1, but not on Android 4.4.4, sadly.

I was thinking that maybe my logging process could be the problem, but destroying that process in my activity's onDestroy()-method didn't solve the issue either.

Starting the logging process:

```
logger = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-v", "time", "-f", logcatFile.getAbsolutePath(), " *:E"});
```

Stopping it:

```
logger.destroy();
```

Comment: Why are you starting a different process?

Comment: I followed a guide at some point. I just wanted to output logcat to a file, and this is what worked. Should I not be doing this?

Comment: You should do it if and only if you know what you're doing. Why do you even need this?

Comment: I want to be able to send a logfile to myself, so I can read it on the computer? :s

Comment: You could use Android Studio for this. Logcat can be accessed via adb and is strongly protected from most other access methods. Or just use `adb logcat ...` https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't contains any logging information, nor did you provide a stacktrace with it. Your splash screen doesn't seem to be the issue, but you should replace the new thread with a delayed post to a handler to the looper thread (main thread) you're running in:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}, 1500);
```

Instead of `getApplicationContext()` you could also use `SplashActivity.this` directly.

In your `MainActivity` you then need to make sure to **unbind** the service. Maybe also stop it, depending on what you need it for. Refer to [Bound Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) for more documentation and examples.

For making the `Service` terminate the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) states

> A service can be both **started** and **have connections bound** to it. In such a case, the system will **keep the service running** as long as either it is started or there are one or more connections to it with the Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag. Once **neither** of these situations hold, the service's `onDestroy()` method is called and the service is effectively terminated.

That's why it works when the service isn't started at all. You try to stop the service in `onDestroy()` which is only called if the service is stopped. Your code looks like the service doesn't need to be started at all. But to do it correctly, just stop the service in the acivity's `onDestroy()` or utilize 
[`onUnbind()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onUnbind(android.content.Intent)) or any other useful lifecycle event of the activity or service.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I really appreciate your help.
I am writing to logcat throughout my application, I don't know what to pick, I just figured that I must be doing something fundamentally wrong, but I can't figure out where in the code I am screwing up.

I do unbind my service, and I try to stop it, as well, but to no avail.

Comment: Maybe just don't start it. If you spawn some more threads make sure these are terminated too.

Comment: If I don't start my service at all, then there doesn't seem to be a problem anymore. Hmm... I'll give it another look tomorrow. Thank you, though. I cannot for the life of me figure this out myself.

Comment: Hi tynn.

I appreciate you trying to help me, it has at least caused a bit of refactoring, which has helped a little bit, so thank you. I guess it is impossible for you to fix my problem, when I can't really show it to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you start a service, depends how you define your service in the AndroidManifest.xml, if you have android:process=":yourProcess", if the process name start with ":" it will create a new process, that probably your log output multiple times.